# All rows are going as one row to stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I am sending a datatable's data to a stored procedure which simply inserts the data into the table, but I get an error

> Procedure or function usp_InsertData has too many arguments specified.

When I used profiler to see what going on I found out that all rows are going to the stored procedure as one row.

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

public static void InsertData(DataTable dt)
{
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = strConnString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = ("usp_InsertData");
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstIssue", dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RTitle", dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFirstName", dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RLastName", dt.Rows[i][3].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAddress1", dt.Rows[i][4].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAddress2", dt.Rows[i][5].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAddress3", dt.Rows[i][6].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RCity", dt.Rows[i][7].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RZip", dt.Rows[i][8].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RCounty", dt.Rows[i][9].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RCountry", dt.Rows[i][10].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTitle", dt.Rows[i][11].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PFirstName", dt.Rows[i][12].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLastName", dt.Rows[i][13].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAddress1", dt.Rows[i][14].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAddress2", dt.Rows[i][15].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAddress3", dt.Rows[i][16].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCity", dt.Rows[i][17].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PZip", dt.Rows[i][18].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCounty", dt.Rows[i][19].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCountry", dt.Rows[i][20].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubscriberAccountNumber", dt.Rows[i][21].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnSaleDate", dt.Rows[i][22].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subscriber", dt.Rows[i][23].ToString());

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("data inserted");
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: This code should raise an exception on the second loop. You can't call AddWithValue a second time with the same parameter's name without clearing the collection first

Comment: why are you doing this twice `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();` also you should wrap all you Sql Objects around a `using(){}` and put the for loop inside the using or separate the forloop out into a separate method ect...

Comment: if you want a simple method that will utilize executing sql Insert for example and parsing the params I will post a simple method that you can use it's much cleaner than what you are currently doing

Comment: sure, I would like to use simple method, that's how I can learn more. Thanks

Comment: Don't ever do `throw ex;`, you cause your code to loose the stack trace if you do. either do `throw;` which acts like you wanted `throw ex;` to behave or create a new exception and pass ex in as a inner exception `throw new YourNewException("someInfo", ex);`. Also, for your example it is pointless to catch and then just throw without doing anything, instead of doing `throw;` you can just get rid of the try-catch, it will have the same behavior.

Comment: what does the `Insert statement look like your error `usp_InsertData has too many arguments specified.` is pretty self explanatory it means that if you have 26 values for instance you are passing but the stored proc is expecting 25 ...you're passing too many parameters to the stored procedure

Comment: As @MethodMan says the declaration of the stored procedure doesn't expect so many parameters. Can you add the first lines of the sp (just the list of the parameters expected)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code raises an exception when it reaches the second loop because the parameter collection of the command is already filled with the parameter names and calling again AddWithValue with the same name throws the exception.

You could call the `Parameters.Clear()` method at each loop but a better solution is to create all the parameters before entering the loop, then inside the loop set the value for the current row without recreating the parameters list.

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertData", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstIssue", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    .... add the other parameters specifying the correct datatype .....

    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@FirstIssue"].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        ... other parameters values follows here ....

        // If you don't use the exception don't catch it....
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Notice also that the disposable objects like connection and command should be created inside a using block to ensure proper close and disposing also in case of exceptions

Comment: Excellent explanation @Steve especially in the `Parameters.Clear +1` you may want to explain to the OP why it's better to use the `using` vs explicitly calling close and dispose as well

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a parameter with the same key to the parameterlist for each loop.

Add `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` statement at the end of the loop to clear the parameters before the next loop begins, then it should work.

On a side note, there are a lot of performance issues in your code.

Comment: 1) you can create parameters outside the loop, then assign values inside the loop. 2) you are not clearing or destroying the cmd object. 3) If you can modify stored procedure, you can modify it to accept an entire datatable, instead of sending in one row at a time, this becomes a overhead to the application if there are millions of rows in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a lot simpler and perform better. Instead of doing your inserts row by agonizing row you could instead use a table valued parameter. You would create your own custom table type to match that of the columns you are inserting. Then instead of all this iteration you simply call a single procedure one time and pass your entire dataset as one parameter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx